# Replace options for select tag rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I want to replace the current options for a select tag with the values in an array
My form

```
<%= f.select :nick_names,[" "], { prompt: "Select Nicknames" }, { :multiple => true, class: 'selectpicker', required: true }  %>
```

In my js I am trying

```
var data = ["robb", "sansa", "arya", "bran", "rickon", "SNOW"]

$("#form_nick_names").empty(); //remove all previous options

for(i = 0;i<data.length;i++){ 
  $("#form_nick_names").append( 
    $("<option></option>").attr("value", data[i]).text(data[i])
  );
}
```

Doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Can you share what the output HTML looks like?

Comment: Please explain what "doesn't seem to work" means.

Comment: @margo the previous [" "] value is not replaced by contents of data array

Comment: That's work, can't reproduce https://jsfiddle.net/q643x5q4/

Answer (score 0):

I"m not sure empty works in this situation. This should work

```
$("#form_nick_names option").remove(); //remove all previous options

var length = data.length
for(i = 0; i < length; i++){ 
  $("#form_nick_names").append("<option value=" + data[i] + ">" + data[i] + "</option")}
}
```

I tend to pre-set the length in a var for a loop so it only is calculated once, otherwise it gets calculated each time the loop runs.